# The longest gap between a movie and its sequel

Tags: sequels

[Dumb and Dumber To](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2096672/) is to be released later this year, 20 years after the original [Dumb & Dumber](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109686/).

This motivates me to ask what is the longest gap between release date of a movie and its sequel. Here, by sequel, I consider only movies where characters are portrayed by the same actors as in the original.

Some other examples of long gaps that come to mind are

16 years - [The Godfather: Part II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562) (1974) and [The Godfather: Part III](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099674) (1990)

30 years - [The Odd Couple](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063374) (1968) and [The Odd Couple II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120773) (1998)

But what is the longest gap?

Comment: Not 20, **Dumb and Dumberer: When Harry Met Lloyd** came in 2003 making the gap of only 11 years.

Comment: That was a prequel without original cast

Comment: Star Wars had some time between them as well, but probably not a record breaker.

Comment: @DustinDavis agreed Return of the Jedi was (1983) Episode VII is scheduled for (2015) - 32 years.

Comment: You need to put your specific criteria in your question. Are you looking ONLY for sequels (no prequels? What about reboots?) and ONLY original cast? (ALL of the original cast? Partial?)

Comment: Fairly comprehensive list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_gaps_between_film_sequels (Disney seems to be the king of sequels)

Comment: @BenPlont  Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith was 2005, 22 years.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer OP specifies "characters played by the same actors". As far as that goes, I would measure from Jedi to VII. They've both got Mark Hamill, Carrie Fisher and Harrison Ford. I suppose you could make a case for Anthony Daniels and Kenny Baker the go from III to VII. But episode III is a prequel, not a sequel.

Comment: Not happened yet, but it would be interesting to see if a sequel to Serenity will happen and when!

Comment: @DustinDavis & BenPlont, if you consider sequels, films that involve the same "universe" then the span of RotJ to PM (which is 16 years, for the record) isn't correct.  We can't forget the two Ewok movies! (Battle for Endor and... the other one.)

Comment: Zatoichi deserves at least an honorable mention. It's a long running series of Samaria films spanning at least 41 years with the same actor, comprising 26 films and also television.

Comment: [There's an entire wiki page on this topic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_gaps_between_film_sequels)

Comment: Ok. Strange. Does anybody care to explain 3 down votes?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

TVTropes unimaginatively calls this [Sequel Gap](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SequelGap), and has a fairly extensive list.

The longest gap they have with actors in common in the Live-Action Film section are the Brazilian films [**Esta Noite Encarnarei no Teu Cadáver  (1967)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060380/) (a.k.a. This Night I'll Possess Your Corpse) and [**Encarnação do Demônio (2008)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0923683/) (a.k.a. Embodiment of Evil) which both star [José Mojica Marins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0596261/) as The Gravedigger, [Zé do Caixão](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0026883/) (loosely translated to *Coffin Joe*) which is an astonishing **41 year gap**.

Though this is debatable as it's not a direct sequel, but parts 2 and 3 of a [trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mojica_Marins#The_Coffin_Joe_trilogy) which began with [**À Meia-Noite Levarei Sua Alma (1964)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059440/) (a.k.a At Midnight I Will Take Your Soul).

Another shorter option from the same list is [**The Naked Civil Servant (1975)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073438/) and its direct sequel [**An Englishman in New York (2009)**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0997057/) which both star [John Hurt](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000457/) as [Quentin Crisp](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0042344/) which is a **34 year gap**.

Comment: Oh, a TVTropes link. I'll just quickly read that one page and then get back to work.

Answer (score 18):

This might be considered cheating, but there's the [The Nutty Professor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nutty_Professor_%282008_film%29) from 2008 which is a sequel to the [1963 comedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nutty_Professor). It's a **45 years gap, and Jerry Lewis reprised his role as Julius Kelp in it**. However, it's animated and the original was live action.

Also noteworthy is [Belle toujours](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475224/combined) from 2006, the sequel to Luis Bunuel's [Belle de jour](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061395/combined) from 1967 in which Michel Piccoli reprised his role as Henri Husson **39 years later**.

You can find more suggestions on Wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_gaps_between_film_sequels).

Comment: Regarding *The Nutty Professor*, there was also [the 1996 remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nutty_Professor_(1996_film)), which had [its own sequel in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutty_Professor_II:_The_Klumps).

Answer (score 12):

My favorite is [The Hustler](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054997/) (1961), where Paul Newman reprises the role of "Fast" Eddie Felson 25 years later in [The Color of Money](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090863/) (1986).

Answer (score 4):

Czech films "Sněženky a machři" (1982) and "Sněženky a machři po 25 letech" (2008), translated as "Snowdrops and Aces" and "Snowdrops and Aces, 25 years after", share a lot of the original cast. That did not help the sequel much, though.

Answer (score 1):

In Mollywood (India):

Irupatham Nootandu (Twentieth Century) -1987 :: Sagar Alias Jacky - 2009 - 22 years

Mannar Mathai Speaking - 1995 :: Mannar Mathai Speaking 2 - 2014 - 19 years

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your perspective, one could make a argument about the documentaries 7 Up and 56 Up, which are 49 years apart.  These were the first and eighth installations of this series, though, where each subsequent sequel was only 7 years later.

Comment: If there was one every 7 years, that's really no 49 year gap.

Answer (score 0):

For Main Steam movies: Star wars was 1977  next year Episode 7 will be released so that will be **38 year gap**

Since you did not include 'Dumb and Dumberer" number 2 I will assume you mean from first movie to last in series.

Comment: well his example of Dumb & Dumber did not illustrate that

Comment: *"I will assume you mean from first movie to last in series."* - No, he doesn't, he simply didn't include that *Dumb and Dumber* sequel because it didn't feature the original actors, but *Return of the Jedi* did very well, which makes your answer only 32 years.

Comment: Episode 6 was already released. 7 is the new one.

Answer (score -2):

I believe some Disney movies might hold this record. Bambi was over 60 years,
Cinderella and Peter Pan around 50 years or so.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is after movies where "characters are portrayed by the same actors as in the original".

Comment: If they got the same voice actors to reprise their roles, that might qualify.

Answer (score -3):

Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade (1989) 
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull (2008)

19 years

Comment: There are already other answers with proven, longer periods of time. Please refrain from making additional answers that amount to nothing more than a list of answers.